# RobotFramework&SeleniumLibarary. How to execute javascript with my webElement?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Here is my code:

```
Go To Confirm
[Arguments]     ${tr}
${btns}    Call Method
...        ${tr}
...        find_elements_by_tag_name
...        button

FOR    ${btn}   IN   @{btns}
${btnText}   get text   ${btn}
run keyword if     '${btnText}'=='confirm'    click element   ${btn}
exit for loop if   '${btnText}'=='confirm'
END
```

There are two elements that overlap.When I 'click element'.And received this error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-show="selectedClassify.label === 
'waitConfirm' &amp;&amp; (!buttonConfig || buttonConfig &amp;&amp; 
buttonConfig.confirmScheme == 1)" ng-click="confirmBtn(row)">...</button> 
is not clickable at point (768, 581). 
Other element would receive the click: 
<footer class="infi-footer display-none ng-scope display-block" ng-if="!notFooter &amp;&amp; 
!hideLayout" ng-class=" {true: 'display-block'}[!notFooter &amp;&amp; !hideLayout]">... 
</footer> 
(Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.163) Stacktrace: #0 0x55817bb9b7a9 <unknown>
```

I want to fix it like this:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));        
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

or this:

```
WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.id("navigationPageButton")); 
JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", myelement);
```

I find the keyword "Execute Javascript" in docs. But it has no parameter about webElement.

How to execute javascript with my webElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Execute Javascript](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Execute%20Javascript) allows you to pass arguments. Within the script itself you reference the arguments via `arguments` array.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
Execute Javascript    arguments[0].click()  ARGUMENTS  ${btn}
```